# "Интеллектуальный" поиск по словарю в Postgres (Laravel)

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

Есть словарь переводов научных терминов. Если ввести запрос

**LIKE %line%** - выведет:

```
approaching line
online reservation
line
liner
```

Но нужен следующий порядок:

```
line
approaching line
online reservation
liner
```

Уже написал выборку из БД, но не знаю как сделать вывод в нужном порядке

```
$Obj = RussianModel::where(function ($query) use ($search) {
    // ТОЧНОЕ СОВПАДЕНИЕ
    $query->where('translate', 'ILIKE', '' . $search . ''); // Точное совпадение
    $query->orWhere('translate', 'ILIKE', '' . $search . ' %'); // Слово в начале строки
    $query->orWhere('translate', 'ILIKE', '% ' . $search . ''); // Слово в конце строки
    $query->orWhere('translate', 'ILIKE', '% ' . $search . ' %'); // Слово в середине строки

    // ЧАСТИЧНОЕ СОВПАДЕНИЕ
    $query->orWhere('translate', 'ILIKE', '%' . $search . '%'); // Любое возможное совпадение
})->get();
```

Уже делал 5 последовательных запросов, объединял результаты. Но это не очень хорошо. Может есть другой способ поиска?

Comment: в чем интересно логика того порядка, который нужен? у PgSQL вот логика понятная - по алфавиту. Чтобы писать операторы нужно сначала логически описать задачу. "Интеллектуальный" вовсе не значит "лишенный логики", согласны? ;-)

Comment: в том что с начала выводится точное соответствие запросу, а затем различные производные. если сделать 5 запросов , а потом merge ответов - то получится всё как надо. Просто вывод по ID - совсем не правильное решение

Comment: тогда создавайте второе поле с regex на проверку вхождения целого слова, сортируйте по этому полю - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html